# MySQL: optimal configs / methods for ALTER of large MyISAM table to InnoDB (17gb+)

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, alter-table, my.cnf

I have a large MySQL (5.1) MyISAM table (13gb table, 4GB indexes - 40mm+ records)

- I'm going to be converting this table to InnoDB in a production environment.

The DB is on a cloud server with 8GB of RAM (will likely upgrade to 30GB RAM just for the conversion).

**One method to do this** is to simple write an ALTER query:

> **What settings and configs would be optimal to convert in this way as quickly and smoothly as possible?**

Some of the suggested settings I've read:

- large innodb_buffer_pool_size (is 4GB the largest possible?)
- preread your old myisam data/index files using shell commands
- increase innodb_log_file_size (what's best size in the case?)
- Do the alter table in X parallel threads, where X is the qty of CPU cores on your server **(how can you do this?)**
- other minor tweaks (innodb_doublewrite=0, innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0)

> Note: Similar question here (but *much smaller* table example with
>   different server size):
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081823/speeding-up-conversion-from-myisam-to-innodb/2081871#2081871

Of course, there are **other methods** to do this like:

- Do a MYSQLDUMP of the old table and reinsert into a new clean InnoDB table,
- Run "SELECT * ... INSERT INTO... " query, or
- Run "SELECT INTO OUTFILE..." query on old table and then a "LOAD DATA INFILE... " query into the new table

---

**1. How would you configure your settings for the purpose of making this alter go as quickly and as smoothly as possible?**

**2. Which method do you think is the best alternative?**